# Parameter 'id' to be query string in Grails redirection

Tags: grails, redirect

From Grails controller, I want to redirect to this (using query string):

> /mycontroller/myaction?id=3

I wrote this code:

```
def a = 3;
redirect (controller:"mycontroller",action:"myaction",params:[id:a])
```

This code will produces:

> /mycontroller/myaction/3

I know that 'id' is special parameter. It will be url not query string. I try another parameter

```
def name = "John";
redirect (controller:"mycontroller",action:"myaction",params:[name:name])
```

will produces:

> /mycontroller/myaction?name=John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your described behavior is a result of your [UrlMappings](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html) configuration.
If you use the default mapping, the `id` parameter will be put in the at the described position `$id?`:

```
class UrlMappings {    
    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }
        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

In general this is no problem. You could also use the `id` parameter as if it was set as query string:

```
def myaction() {
    def idFromParams = params.id
}
```

Or you simply rewrite your `UrlMappings`.